# Is there any way to replace chain '.map'...'.map'...'.pluck'...'.map' with something more effective?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
[
    { "time": "Mon May 14 2018", "points": { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} },
    { "time": "Mon May 14 2017", "points": { "a": 5, "b": 6, "c": 7} }
]
```

I need to convert that in to format like:

```
[
 {
  eventTime:"Mon May 14 2018",
  series: [
    {
      name: "a",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      name: "b",
      value: 2
    },
    {
      name: "c",
      value: 3
    }
  ]
 },
 {
  eventTime:"Mon May 14 2017",
  series: [
    {
      name: "a",
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: "b",
      value: 6
    },
    {
      name: "c",
      value: 7
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

I have a piece of code that making a transformation:

```
.map(x =>
  x.map(y => _.pick(y, ['time', 'event'])).map(z => ({
    name: z.eventTime,
    series: [
      {
        name: 'a',
        value: z.event.a
      },
      {
        name: 'b',
        value: z.event.b
      },
      {
        name: 'c',
        value: z.event.c
      }
    ]
  }))
)
```

Do you think there is a better way of doing so?
I saw there is a function [_.transform](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#transform) but didn't figure out how it might help in my case.

Not looking for solution with a pure `for..each` loops

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[
    { time: "Mon May 14 2018", points: { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} },
    { time: "Mon May 14 2017", points: { "a": 5, "b": 6, "c": 7} }
].map(obj => ({
    eventTime: obj.time,
    series: [
        { name: "a", value: obj.points.a },
        { name: "b", value: obj.points.b },
        { name: "c", value: obj.points.c }
    ]
}))
```

or

```
[
    { time: "Mon May 14 2018", points: { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} },
    { time: "Mon May 14 2017", points: { "a": 5, "b": 6, "c": 7} }
].map(obj => ({
    eventTime: obj.time,
    series: Object.keys(obj.points).map(key => ({ name: key, value: obj.points[key] }))
}))
```

Comment: I just noticed that I really didn't need lodash `pick` and third(last) `.map` operators. The option 1 works well seems like

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with just `map` method and ES6 parameter destructuring.

```js
let data = [{ "time": "Mon May 14 2018", "points": { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}}, { "time": "Mon May 14 2017", "points": { "a": 5, "b": 6, "c": 7}}]

let result = data.map(({time, points}) => ({
  eventTime: time,
  series: Object.entries(points).map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}))
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `Object.entries` is from ES2017 and might need to be polyfilled for older browsers.